# AppleScript: How to check if something is a directory or a file

Tags: applescript

**Update:** Solution below

---

Say you have a list of selected items from Finder. Say there are some files, folders, various bundles, and even some applications included in the selection.

Now say you only want those items that are (in UNIX terms) *directories*. I.e. you only want items you can `cd` to in the terminal.

You can check each item's `kind` property and see if it equals "Folder", but that doesn't work for application bundles or other bundles/packages, though they are in fact "folders" (directories)

If the items are actual file objects (not aliases), you can check each item's `class` property... except that doesn't always work either, since bundles are now "document file" instances, and applications are "application file" instances.

It's worse if you only have a list of aliases rather than actual file objects, since you can't check the `class` property; it'll always just say "alias".

The only solutions I can think of, are to either get the POSIX path of each item, and see if it has a trailing forward slash, or to send its path to a script written in a different language, which can check if something's a directory or not.

Both ideas seem crazy to me. Checking for a trailing forward slash is extremely hacky and fragile, and feeding everything to a different script is complete overkill.

---

**Update:** What Asmus suggests below does seem to be <strike>the only</strike> a good solution<strike>, as it seems there's no way for AppleScript to figure it out on its own</strike>:

```
do shell script "file -b " & filePosixPath
```

That'll return the string "directory" for folder, bundles, applications, packages, etc. etc.
But note(!) that for disks, it returns "sticky directory".

Here's a generalized function that works pretty well

```
on isDirectory(someItem) -- someItem is a file reference
    set filePosixPath to quoted form of (POSIX path of (someItem as alias))
    set fileType to (do shell script "file -b " & filePosixPath)
    if fileType ends with "directory" then return true
    return false
end isDirectory
```

Comment: Well, I´d say the easiest solution is to hand POSIX paths over to the command line tool `file`, where e.g. `file -b /Applications/Safari.app` simply returns "directory". It should be easy enough to incorporate that in a `do shell script` loop.

Comment: @Asmus: You're probably right. After I wrote the question I realized that I could just do a quick shell command rather than a full-on shell script. Still, it just seems strange to have to go outside AppleScript to figure out something as basic as whether or not something's a directory. I'll leave the question up for a day or so, and in the meantime feel free to write you comment as an answer so you can get the points :)

Comment: @Flambino I can't upvote your good question because I used all my votes up! :(

Comment: @fireshadow52: Heh, well it's the thought that counts – thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a simple applescript solution. You can check if something is a "package" using system events.

```
tell application "Finder" to set theItems to (selection) as alias list

set canCDItems to {}
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with anItem in theItems
        if anItem is package folder or kind of anItem is "Folder" or kind of anItem is "Volume" then
            set end of canCDItems to contents of anItem
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
return canCDItems
```

Comment: Interesting! Odd that that vocabulary is buried in System Events rather than Finder, but at least it exists. I ended up using Asmus' solution, but you answered the original question, so hat tip (and checkmark) to you. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. System Events was created to take the load off the Finder. Basically the Finder is often busy with computer-related tasks so it's best to ask system events to do things instead of the Finder when possible. As such system events can do most of the things the Finder can do and sometimes even more. I would suggest any time you're thinking of using the Finder that you check if system events can do it instead.

Comment: Thanks for background info. I didn't know that was the genesis of System Events, but it makes a lot of sense. I'll be taking a closer look at System Events' dictionary now. Much obliged!

Comment: I would rather use `class of anItem is folder` and `class of anItem is disk` as the strings are localized.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is just a string, use this form:

```
on isDirectory(someItem) -- someItem is a string
    set filePosixPath to quoted form of (POSIX path of someItem)
    set fileType to (do shell script "file -b " & filePosixPath)
    if fileType ends with "directory" then return true
    return false
end isDirectory
```

Answer (score 1):

Im using an alfred workflow which run this script with a keyboard combination of keys (⎇+F2).
The script opens a terminal application based on what I got selected on finder, if is a folder then open a terminal inside selected folder, if is a file then open a terminal on parent folder.
worked flawless

```
set pathList to "~"
if frontmost of application "Finder" then
    tell application "Finder"
        set fileList to selection as alias list
        if fileList is not equal to {} then
            set someItem to (item 1 of fileList) as text
            set filePosixPath to quoted form of (POSIX path of someItem)
            set fileType to (do shell script "file -b " & filePosixPath)
            if fileType ends with "directory" then
                set pathList to filePosixPath
            else
                set pathList to (quoted form of POSIX path of (folder of the front window as alias))
            end if
        else
            set pathList to (quoted form of POSIX path of (folder of the front window as alias))
        end if
        
    end tell
end if
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        if exists window 1 then
            do script ("cd " & pathList) in window 1
        else
            do script ("cd " & pathList)
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed this today, as I was trying to plug a couple of diff tools into Finder for Mountain Lion and wanted to check if the selected item or items were folders or files. This worked for me:

```
tell application "Finder"
  set sel1 to the selection
  set class1 to class of (item 1 of sel1)
  set cs to (class1 as string)
  ...
  if cs = "folder" or cs contains "class cfol" then
    set choice to display alert "Which tool?" buttons {"opendiff", "diffmerge"}
    set tool to (button returned of choice)
```

I found I needed to test cs for both cases, depending on whether I was running in the AppleScript Editor or as a result of clicking a toolbar button on Finder. Far from the neatest but, shorter than the previous AppleScript-only solution, this would be my alternative proposal

```
on isDirectory(someItem)
  ((class of someItem) as string) contains "fol"
end isDirectory
```

Results of full testing in all circumstances welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Standard Additions offers this (no System Events necessary):

```
set isBundleType to package folder of (info for (choose file))
```